# Standard way to start and stop StanfordCoreNLP server in python?

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess, stanford-nlp

I used subprocess to start CoreNLP server,

1. `command = 'java -mx4g -cp "*;stanford-corenlp-full-2017-06-09/*" edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLPServer -port 9000 -timeout 15000'`
2. `server  = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)`

to stop the server i have used :

3. `server.kill()`

for the first time running there is no problem,

if i try to start all the above steps again, then it is giving an error:

> error is:

```
    java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.httpserver.ServerImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.httpserver.HttpServerImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.httpserver.DefaultHttpServerProvider.createHttpServer(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer.create(Unknown Source)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLPServer.run(StanfordCoreNLPServer.java:1277)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLPServer.main(StanfordCoreNLPServer.java:1369)
```

could anyone help me out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should send a shutdown message with the shutdown key.  Here is an example command line call:

```
wget "localhost:9000/shutdown?key=`cat /tmp/corenlp.shutdown`" -O -
```

You could execute such a command with `subprocess` or `os.system` etc...

Note that the shutdown key is located at `/tmp/corenlp.shutdown` unless you specify a different name.

If you want to be nicer you could also use the `requests` library:

```
import requests

from commands import getoutput

url = "http://localhost:9000/shutdown?"
shutdown_key = getoutput("cat /tmp/corenlp.shutdown")
r = requests.post(url,data="",params={"key": shutdown_key})
```

That will transmit the shutdown message to the server as well.

Comment: Thanks @StanfordNLP, source found here https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/corenlp-server.html#stopping-the-server